# Keyboard shortcut helper app for windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for an app like KeyCue for the Mac that will reveal all the keyboard shortcuts for the app you are currently using. For example in Photoshop the app would display a list of all the photoshop keyboard commands. Such a thing might not be possible on windows.

Are there any?

Comment: See also ["Is there any way to get a list of the system-wide keyboard shortcuts currently in use?"](http://superuser.com/questions/298484/).

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on such a software. Our beta work with Microsoft Excel and will take a while until we make our way to photoshop http://www.veodin.com.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I wanted. I just don't need it for excel :P

Comment: Which applications are you interested most?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, a long time ago, I found some programs that you could pay for. For now, I suppose you just have to use shortcut guides. I'll keep looking... Here's some for now, but I'll find some better ones.

- http://lifehacker.com/learn-all-the-windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts-with-this-c-1731058220

---- Edit:

After some digging around in my pocket, I found this article: http://goo.gl/9qeSxZ. In here, you'll find **Key Rocket** as Lifehacker's favorite choice. It's $135/year though. I think that's really expensive, but there's an evaluation copy. **Shortcutfoo** is an online program that helps you master them, but it doesn't install on your computer. From a quick observation, it looks like an awesome version of flashcard training. Hope this all helps!

*Removed Gmail Guide: Superuser won't let me post more than 2 links until I have 10+ reputation.